# Tomcat deployment through Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, continuous-deployment

I am new to Jenkins. I am trying to deploy my sample spring boot (maven) application in tomcat through Jenkins build job. But it shows error like "Connection refused". But My tomcat user details and Jenkins tomcat 8X credential is also same. I tried with localhost and machine IP also.

Please anyone help me. Thanks.

For your reference

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5J8r.png)

[Build job tomcat credential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOxKZ.png)

[Tomcat-User.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSUiB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to start tomcat before deploying. :)